# pipenv installing package is occuring `ModuleNotFoundError` without pip install

Tags: python, pipenv

pipenv installing package have some problem to me.

becaouse of ModuleNotFoundError, I must to execute pip install command

like `pip install python-dotenv`.

Do pip is needed even though using pipenv?

ModuleNotFoundError is occuring everytime.

- environment: VSCODE remote-container(default simple setting)
- python 3.x

pipfile

```
python-dotenv = "==0.17.1"
```

run command

```
pipenv install packages
pipenv shell (<-- I am not sure this is needed in my case.)
python myprogram.py
```

the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_program.py", line 11, in <module>
    import script.common.settings as settings
  File "/workspaces/my_project/script/common/settings.py", line 3, in <module>
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

Is there any idea of this ? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
pipenv run python myprogram.py
```

`pipenv shell` on the other hand is used to activate your python virtual environment, something like `source venv/bin/activate` if you have used the default `venv` module before. `pipenv` works by creating virtual environment for you when you do `pipenv install <module>`. Hence when you do `pipenv shell` you are using python as if you are in the virtual environment (of course there are more to this as it uses sub-shell which is technically different from just the terminal process).

I personally do not recommend using `pipenv shell`, just use `pipenv run` to keep things clean. This is because when you have multiple projects/virtual environments running, you may simply forget to exit and later installed module in the wrong directory. You can create alias for `pipenv run` as well to make it easier to type, such as `pipr`.